# How to write a java web service to do remote login?

Tags: java, web-services

I have two application. I need to do a single signon from application a to application b.

I thinking of using web service. I wonder how do i go about that approach.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming these are web applications - you must implement some type of shared trust model between the applications.

Under no circumstance should you write your own. That is too easy to screw up and there are plenty of existing (both open and commercial) to choose from.

Here are following options:
1 - If everyone is running Windows - you could just Windows Native Authentication (aka SPNEGO)
2 - You could implement some type of SSO system. Popular systems are CAS, Oracle Access Manager, CA SiteMinder, Sun SSO and IBM Tivoli Access Manager. While CAS is open-source, the others will also allow you to implement authorization as well, while CAS only does authentication.

Finally - make sure whatever option you choose - that it integrates with your language's native authentication & authorization framework. In Java this would be JAAS. In .NET it would be the .NET security framework. For PHP/Perl  - you can leverage Apache modules. The benefit is that you don't have to become a security expert and it will make it easier to use external systems for authentication & authorization without having to re-code your app.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a public key authentication scheme.

Create a keypair with a public and private key (using Java's keytool, GNU GPG or a similiar tool). Use the private key to sign a piece of information (for example a username) on application A and create a link to application B that is accessible from application A and contains the signed data. Application B can then log the user on after verifying with the public key that the request indeed came from application A (which it must have if it is able to decrypt the string).

You could of course create a opposite keypair for navigating the other way as well, or you could just use the public key and keep it secret (effectively making it a shared-secret system).

If the user tries to access application B directly you could also redirect him to application A with a parameter that says he came from application B (or do a referrer check). If he is already logged on to application A create the link with the signed data and redirect to it, otherwise present him with a logon screen and redirect after logon.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an existing open source product, [CAS](http://www.ja-sig.org/products/cas/) and just implement it instead of develop your own.  That way you'll be able to integrate with other applications that support the same protocol.  Even if you decide to implement your own instead of using their code, there are a lot of ideas presented at the web site that would be useful for you to consider.

Answer (score 0):

If the applications are hosted in the same server, then you could configure it to use single sign on. For example, in Tomcat this is achieved with a [Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/host.html#Single%20Sign%20On).

If the applications are in different environments, then a secured Web Service is a good idea. You could for example create a public - private key pair and have application b (server) authenticating application a (client) on the client certificate. This means that application a will sign all requests to application b with the client certificate. More details about the architecture are needed for a full solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an application server? What is the environment for your applications?

There is a standard for propagating identity using web services called Web Service Security UsernameToken Profile. Here's a quick [overview](http://blogs.msdn.com/thehoggblog/articles/504526.aspx). You can send username/password or various tokens such as X.509 certificate or a SAML assertion. Some application servers web services stacks will handle WSS UsernameToken Profile, JBoss, Websphere, and WebLogic. Otherwise the web service code has to handle it. This approach may be too cumbersome depending on your environment.

There is a standard for single sign-on, called [SAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML). Again, this may be too heavy weight for your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle land I know there is the concept of a trusted application.  Basically if you have control of both applications you can set it up like so:

Application A sends Application B, 1) Application A's username and password and 2) the current user's username.  Since B knows and trusts Application A it doesn't need to verify the user's credentials, since it knows application A has already done that for it.

I assume that if you have a custom application B you might be able to do something like this.  If your SSO implementation supports this then you probably don't have to do a whole lot except design your web services.

Good Luck